# Replace only text inside div and toggle different div content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

**show below jquery code**

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#prvnote').hide();
      $('#regclass').click(function () {
                     $('#prvnote').toggle(400);
                     $('#newdiv').toggle(400);

   });
 });
```

**show below HTML code**
This div only use as menu

```
 <div id="regclass"><span>View Previous Note</span></div>
```

Now when i clicked on above div content then **below div will display** and **above span tag content replace with "Post Note"**

```
 <div id="newdiv"><form>......</form></div>
 <div id="prvnote"><form>......</form></div>
```

When `div(newdiv)` show then span content "Post Note" and when `div(prvnote)` show then span content must be "View Previous Note"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#prvnote,#newdiv').hide();
           $("#regclass").toggle(function () {
               $('#regclass span').text('Post Note');
               $('#prvnote').toggle(400);
               $('#newdiv').toggle(400);
           }, function () {
               $('#regclass span').text('View Previous Note');
               $('#prvnote').toggle(400);
               $('#newdiv').toggle(400);
           });
       });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/6/)

Comment: when my page is load then "#regclass" div cant display. CSS property automatically set to NONE.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <div id="newdiv" style="display:none"><form>......</form></div>
 <div id="prvnote"style="display:none"><form>......</form></div>
 <div id="regclass"><span>View Previous Note</span></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#regclass').click(function () {
alert("Hi");
$("#regclass span").html("").append("POST NOW");
$('#prvnote').css({"display":"block"});
$('#newdiv').css({"display":"block"});

});
```

Check The Fiddler Here

http://jsfiddle.net/ShekharPankaj/3htMG/

Comment: When div(newdiv) show then span content "Post Note" and when div(prvnote) show then span content must be "View Previous Note"

Didn't Saw The Edit

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/7/):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#prvnote').hide();
       $("#regclass").toggle(function () {
           $('#regclass span').text('Post Note');
           $('#prvnote').toggle(400);
           $('#newdiv').toggle(400);
       }, function () {
           $('#regclass span').text('View Previous Note');
           $('#prvnote').toggle(400);
           $('#newdiv').toggle(400);
       });
   });
```

Taken from Sridhar R, i understand you want to show only one div at a time...

Comment: when my page is load then "#regclass" div cant display. CSS property automatically set to NONE.